# I want to show viewbag list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

in my class menu code and description name

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
class menus 
   {
    public string Idmenus { get; set; }

    public string desname { get; set; }  
    }
}
```

in my controller I want to add data to object List

```
  var viewdes = db.menudescriptions.Where(w => w.Idmenu == mids).ToList();
  var desc = new List<menus>();     
  foreach (var b in viewdes) {
           desc.Add(new menus { Idmenus = b.Iddesmenu });
           desc.Add(new menus { desname = b.descriptionname });
       }
       if ((desc.Count != 0))
       {
           ViewBag.Id = desc.ToList();
       }
```

I want to show `ViewBag.Id` To Viewpage?

```
 @if (ViewBag.Id != null)
        {
            <td>
                @foreach (var per in `enter code here`)
                {

         @Html.ActionLink(@per.ToString(), "detail", new { mides = per })

                }
            </td>

        }
```

Comment: ``@foreach (var per in ViewBag.Id as List<menus>)``

Comment: You haven't made it clear what the problem is.

Comment: Chris Pratt : i'm sorry' I want to show description name in action link and get idmenu but I don't know how to it?

Answer (score 0):

You basically just need to iterate your ViewBag.Id like what you normally do when using foreach

```
@foreach(var per in ViewBag.Id as List<menus>)
{
   @Html.ActionLink(per.desname, "detail", new { mides = per })
}
```